# How to target votes to referenced nodes from main node and transfer the same vote to other nodes?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, entities, rating

Lets go by example - I want to create IMDB website on Drupal. I use either [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) or [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/Rate) module to make different rating types - Say Critic Rating, Story Rating, Animation Rating etc.

And these ratings appear on *MOVIES* Content type. Now when user votes on Movie on *User Rating* then the vote should also reflect on the Director's and Producer's Page (CAST content type for all participants in the movie including actors, cameramen, director, producer etc). Similarly when user votes on "Story Rating", then all referenced nodes of CAST content type involved with this field (story) should also be voted.

I am not sure of the structure at present, in the sense in movie content type - I have fields like "story" with referenced node from CAST content type where people who have written the story will be referenced. Also I will have fields called ACTORS - and all actors of the move will be referenced from CAST content type. But this doesnt seem to be the right way to do it as I later cannot filter content based on fields say if I want to see people involved in story - then a filter should be able to do so. But creating a field will not allow me to filter it. Some taxonomy term has to be used.

It'll be great if someone could explain the IMDB way of making the website on drupal with content types in a little detail.

Regards.

Comment: Have you ever tried [Views Reference Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter)?